# Check if there are same elements in two string array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two string arrays that hold values. How can i check if the first array contains an element that is also in the second array? I want to make a loop that checks through if there are any elements that are same in both, then i want to use that value and and display it in a message box. How do i compare them like that?

```
string[] weekDays = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
string[] potenDays = { "Mon", "Tue", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None" };
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var both =  weekDays.Intersect(potenDays);
var count = both.Count();
var daysArray = both.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var weekDay in weekDays.Where(wd => potenDays.Contains(wd)))
{
    // Show weekDay
}
```